# Why My answer deleted

Tags: discussion, support

in below post my answer got's deleted.

[How to get the attribute id by attribute code in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226911/how-to-get-the-attribute-id-by-attribute-code-in-magento-2/226913#226913)

The accepted answer gets updated after my post so how you guys consider my answer as copied

You can see here in revision history https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/226913/revisions

And for further note I checked that method in core and then answer

`vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/Entity/Attribute.php`
In above file I checked `getIdByCode` method and answered as its require two params

Answer (score 1):

Your answer was deleted because It looked almost exactly as a previously posted answer.

Comment: please see answer revision history, he had updated his post, after my answer , you see in , he is wrong , https://magento.stackexchange.com/revisions/226913/2

Comment: Yes, this question has the almost same code. first user posted the answer   first

Comment: @AmitBera But he has updated his answer after my answer. so how my answer is copied ?

Comment: But Sir, @Divyesh has posted the answer and then accepted user has updated post

Comment: this is the original post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/revisions/226913/1

Comment: Thanks for clarification, But  when i saw this answer , the answer was wrong, so i updated my correct answer, But this incident demotivate me to help people at here, Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry this demotivates you. It shouldn't. There are thousands of questions you can answer and one deleted answer should not demotivate you. I had deleted answers in the past and a lot of people did.

Comment: @Marius , I can't believe that someone has deleted your answer

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Why not? I screw up from time to time.